# If we hover over the Icon in AdvanceDataGrid, item hovering effect (slight highlighting) does not appear?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

Hovering effect on AdvanceDataGrid doest not appear if we take mouse cusor over the icon of item. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button inside your renderer and make use of these styles on button:
overIcon
downIcon